# why string.matches and pattern.matches get different results?

Tags: android

```
// pattern 20xx/xx/xx, e.g. 2012/2/22
String Regex_Date_1 = "20\\d\\d/\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}";

String cell = "from 2011/7/31 to 2011/8/15 15:10-17:40,18:30-21:00";
System.out.println(cell);

System.out.println("--- a ---");
System.out.println( cell.matches(Regex_Date_1) );

System.out.println("--- b ---");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Regex_Date_1);
Matcher m = p.matcher(cell);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println( m.group(0) );
}
```

results:

```
from 2011/7/31 to 2011/8/15 15:10-17:40,18:30-21:00
--- a ---
false
--- b ---
2011/7/31
2011/8/15
```

Why string.matches return false? but pattern.matches can get matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `String#matches` will return `true` "if, and only if, this string matches the given regular expression". You can check the documentation here : [String#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)

However `Matcher#find` will return `true` " if, and only if, a subsequence of the input sequence matches this matcher's pattern". The documentation is available here : [Matcher#find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29).

So to sum up - `String#matches` returns true if the whole string is matched by the regex and `Matcher#find` returns true if some subsequence of the String can be matched by the regex.

Comment: thanks, my question can be corrected by --> System.out.println( cell.matches(".*(" + Regex_Date + ").*") );

Comment: I dont' really think so. `.*` will greedily match everything so the rest of the regex will be ignored. You need to use `.*?`  in order to properly match what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Becucase

Regex_Date_1 = "20\d\d/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}";

[matches (String regularExpression)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)

his method returns true only if the regular expression matches the entire input string. `A common mistake is to assume that this method behaves like contains(CharSequence); if you want to match anywhere within the input string, you need to add .*` to the beginning and end of your regular expression.

Comment: thanks, sometimes not only need to add .*   , in my case, i need wrap regular expression as .*(my-regex).*